# It is possible to replace the "*" of hangupOnStar in Twilio (conference) with some other digit

Tags: python, twilio

We need to implement a solution in python through a conference, and after the meeting, the first participant presses a key that is not *, but the number 5, and this performs an action.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. `*` Is the key you must use.

[hangupOnStar](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar)